# RN: authentication InWebAppBrowser/mobile browser when open the link in mobile app

Tags: react-native, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

The Web application used - Nextjs, Cognito, Amplify, Apollo.
React native use the same cognito pool.

How can I authenticate from RN to WEB using an existing cognito pool?
For example, if I click on a link in a mobile app that opens in a mobile browser, or use `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn`, then I have to log in to a specific page (like the dashboard).
Should I somehow hand over the jwtToken or cognito user object into headers?
I think to get in parameters the flag like isMobileBrowser and login when onMount. But I'm not sure how to continue the session in a mobile web browser.

```
const DashboardPage: NextPage = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query?.isMobileBrowser) {
      // Amplify Auth
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Authenticated>
      <Dashboard />
    </Authenticated>
  );
};
```